# How to mute JuMP (using cplex) log progress?

Tags: julia, cplex, julia-jump

How to mute JuMP log progress?
I want to suppress the output of JuMP Using model as CPLEX.

Comment: You could try [`JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl), something like this: `using Suppressor: @suppress; @suppress m = Model(solver = CplexSolver(..other options ))`. The macro uses `Base.redirect_stdout` underneath for you.

Comment: It finally works! Thanks a lot. I really Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know which version of JuMP you are using but I think all you need to do is to pass `CPX_PARAM_SCRIND = 0` option to your Cplex solver.

Prior to v0.19, this should be something like

```
m = Model( solver=CplexSolver(CPX_PARAM_SCRIND = 0, ...other options ) )
```

From v0.19 and so on, something like

```
const SOLVER = CPLEX.Optimizer(CPX_PARAM_SCRIND = 0, ...other options ) # to create an optimizer object
# OR while creating your model 
m = Model(with_optimizer(CPLEX.Optimizer, CPX_PARAM_SCRIND=0, ...other options))
```

Note that `CPX_PARAM_SCRIND` [seems to be renamed](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/SCRIND.html) to `CPXPARAM_ScreenOutput` in newer versions of Cplex and I do not know how `CPLEX.jl` handles this situation or if it needs handling at all. You probably still can use `CPX_PARAM_SCRIND` option directly in newer versions.

If these do not work, you might want to try redirecting `stdout` directly in Julia.

```
tempout = stdout # save stream
redirect_stdout() # redirect to null
# ... run your solver here
redirect_stdout(tempout) #revert back
```

Comment: I tried all but still does not work... Thanks for reply!

Comment: @최시현 Could you share a little bit more info? What version of CPLEX, JuMP are you using? What exactly have you tried in your code? Provide a simple example maybe. What does not work? Do you get an error? I also edited my answer for another possible solution.

Comment: I use CPLEX 1280_ver & Julia 1.1.0.
I have tried m = Model(with_optimizer(CPLEX.Optimizer, CPX_PARAM_SCRIND=0)) and CPXPARAM_ScreenOutput too.
also I tried open Cplexsoverinterface.jl file in src of julia cplex folder and chage CPX_PARAM_SCRIND to 0 but it still not work..

Comment: What Pkg should I import to use redirect_stdout()?

Comment: @최시현 `redirect_stdout` is in `Base`. Are you sure you do not create another model in your code and use it instead? You might also want to report your issue to [`CPLEX.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/CPLEX.jl).

Comment: I am really appreciate your decent reply. still I can not solve the situation..... I also tried second method which use redirect std, however julia says that they do not have any method redirect std..... I import Base but it does not work    I evidently write    using Base      Base.redirect_std()  ..... I can not handle this... what happends in my code eww